# why flutter BottomNavigationBar changes the icon but does not change the page?

Tags: flutter, bottomnavigationview, flutter-navigation, flutter-appbar, flutter-bottomnavigation

Im new to coding and flutter and I have been trying to make my `bottomNavigationBar` change pages from `home page` to `chatroom` but what ever I try is not working , I watched many videos but their `bottomNavigationBar` is inside their body and when I apply what they are doing I get the red line under my `padding` right after body and `return  Scaffold(` right under this  parenthesis before my `appBar:` **image link is at the end of the code**

```
     import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter_rating_bar/flutter_rating_bar.dart';
    import 'package:trading/core/const.dart';
    import 'package:trading/models/apartment_model.dart';
    import 'package:trading/pages/chat.dart';
    import 'package:trading/pages/detail_page.dart';

    class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
    }

    class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
      var data = ApartmentModel.list;

      int _selectedIndex = 0;
       List<Widget> `enter code here`pages=[
       Homepage(),

       Chatroom(),

        ];




      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(


          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            elevation: 0,
            title: Text(
              "find your product",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black87, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.search,
                    color: Colors.black38,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {}),
              IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.filter_list,
                    color: Colors.black38,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {}),
            ],

          ),



bottomNavigationBar: 

   BottomNavigationBar(
      showSelectedLabels: false,
      showUnselectedLabels: false,
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      selectedItemColor: AppColors.stylecolor,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.black38,
        currentIndex: _selectedIndex,




      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(

            icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text("datsa")),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(

            icon: Icon(Icons.chat), title: Text("data"),),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.person), title: Text("data")),
      ],

      ),


  body: 
     pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
  Padding(    
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

    child:   

    Column(

      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          "65 result in your area",
          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black38),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: ListView.builder(

            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            itemCount: data.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (_) => DetailPage(
                          data[index]
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                      },
                      child: _buildItem(context, index));
                },
              ),
            ), 
         //   Container(       child: _builBottomNavigationBar),
          ],

        ),

      ),

    );  
  }
```

[here is a pic of the red line that I was saying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPW85.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

body can take one widget not more, you assign pages and padding if you want both you must use a column

Comment: thank you for answering ,  do u mean that I should make a column in body and place both `bottomNavigationBar` and `Padding` in it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a List of `Widgets` containing your pages, and in the `body` you populate the `Widget` according to the `Selected Index`.

Example:

```
List<Widget> pages=[
  Dashboard(),
  Profile(),
  Settings(),
];
```

then show the page in the body as:

```
body:
   pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
```

Comment: thank you for answering but that's what I exactly tried before , after making the widget and placing my pages in it , when I try to place `pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),` in body I get the red line under my`Padding`

Comment: @RastaMosi make sure you make the pages scrollable.

Comment: my `Homepage` is scrollable but my `Chatroom` just contains an `Scaffold` and  `appBar` in it . do I have do add something to my chatroom page or ? if possible pls show with example because im super new .Thank you

Comment: @RastaMosi you app should not have a `scaffold` in a `scaffold`, `scaffold` is a single top level container, so replace the `scaffold` with a `Container` in your `Homepage` and `Chatroom` pages.

Comment: @Mohammad_Asef ,  @Adnankarim Thank you guys so much  for help , but the problem actually was the wrong placement of my code , after you mentioned ` scaffold` I checked my code and watched a video realized I wasn't placing `BottomNavigatorBar` in my **Main file ** . I still don't know if that's the right way to use it but for now its working fine .